# Matplotlib cmap color-to-number mapping

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently parsing some data with and plotting it with matplotlib. I've produced the following graph[image: clustering of income] with the following code:

```
n = 10000
num_clusters = 8

cluster_values = kmeans(data, num_clusters=num_clusters)
y = np.random.normal(1, 0.1, n)

py.figure(num=1, figsize=figsize)
py.scatter(data[:n], y, c=cluster_values[:n])
py.title("%s clustering of first %d data points with %d clusters" % (data_label, n, num_clusters))
py.show()
```

I'm taking some income data, running it through kmeans to cluster it and then plotting the data with a colormap of the cluster index of each point. What I would like to do is figure out the relationship between colors and the cluster index. I'd like to know that, for example, blue = 2 and green = 0. To put it another way, I want to know what color a point will be assigned based on it's `cluster_value`.

As for the code, the `n=10000` is there to decrease the number of points (I actually have about ~100000, which slows down my computer) and the `np.random.normal` is there to spread out the data.

Comment: you can add `py.colorbar()` before `py.show` to see what color is assigned

Comment: While that's not the ideal solution (and now that I think about it there probably isn't one) it's good enough. I guess I was actually asking the wrong question in my original post. What I really want to find out is the max and min of each cluster which I can just brute force.